# Animation Seems to Explode When Using Multiple Pictures

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, tailwind-css

You see I am using ReactJs and Tailwind for a small personal project. I have a list of 6 images, that I am then rendering like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import Images from "../images";

export default function PictureHeader() {
    const [pictureIndex, setPictureIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const animationRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const node = animationRef.current;

    const pictures: string[] = Images.pictures;

    const removeAnimation = () => {
        node?.className.includes("fade-out")
        ? node.className.replace("fade-out", "fade-in")
        : node?.className.concat(" fade-in");
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        removeAnimation();
        setInterval(() => {
        nextPicture();
    }, 2500);
    });

    const nextPicture = () => {
        const newIndex = (pictureIndex + 1) % pictures.length;
        setPictureIndex(newIndex);
        node?.className.replace("fade-in", "fade-out");
    }

    console.log(pictureIndex);

    return (
    <div className="padding-10 top-0 inset-x-0 place-content-center">
        <div className="w-4/5 select-none relative rounded-lg">
            <div ref={animationRef} className="absolute content-left aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9 cover z-0">
            <img src={pictures[pictureIndex]}  />
            </div>
            <div className="absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 justify-items-center z-10">
            <h1 className="6xl font-dancing">
                Sierra and Adam
            </h1>
            <h2 className="4xl font-dancing">
                Save the date for a match of the Millenia!
            </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

When I run this page, I find that after a few re-renders the pictures shows up in a strange list:
0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3... and so on until the webpage could probably induce seizures. (See the picture below for what I mean.)[image: What the console.log outputs...]

Am I missing something with this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I am stupid and forgot that you must clear the interval:

```js
    React.useEffect(() => {
        removeAnimation();
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            nextPicture();
        }, 2500);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    });
```

I assume this is because this is just adding more and more interval
s to change the state as it runs so eventually you are just exploding through the queue.